# How to create database migrations in Ruby on Rails without Using Scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create the Model and everything on my own without using the scaffolding in Ruby on Rails. I create the following class:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base 

end
```

Now, I want to add a table Dogs. I am using sqlite3. I think I need to write migration manually!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 2:

ruby script/generate migration CreateDogs

Rails 3:

rails g migration CreateDogs

Comment: But how do I create a migration file since it has special naming? Or is it possible to perform the scaffolding and not edit the view and the controller files.

Comment: What do you mean it has special naming?  The only naming issue is that the class name has to match the file name.  In Reuben's example above, you would get a file db/migrate/<timestamp>_create_dogs.rb which inside would start with "class CreateDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration".  CreateDogs matches create_dogs so you're good.

Comment: But how do I create the timestamp part?

Comment: Oh and in case you were talkingg about the timestamp it's just a string that gets saved in the db when the migration is successfully run: this way, rails keeps track of which migrations have already been run by storing the timestamp strings in the db.

Comment: Let me ask this in a different way. Is there anyway to run scaffold and not alter the controllers and views.

Comment: You create the timestamp part by either a) doing what reuben suggested or b)  writing your own.  look at a previous migration and increment the number(s) at the end.  It's just the current date and time concatenated together but it doesn't matter: the only thing to bear in mind is that rails will run them in order, so make it only a bit later than your last one, so it will be before the next one that you generate, if you know what i mean.

Comment: I think you can do scaffold:model or something can't you?  I never bother with the scaffolds myself and i've not used rails 3.  TBH if you don't want the controllers and views there's no point bothering with scaffolding anyway, just make your own model and migration by hand, which is what i thought you were trying to do anyway.

Comment: I got my answer by running the following: rails generate model Dog .. This will create only the model and the migration and it will not alter the controllers or views.

Comment: Cool.  It's still worth doing it by hand as an exercise in understanding what's going on though.